# How is overtraining dangerous and how to know your limits?

Tags: overtraining

I am looking for a low-down on how excessive training affects your body. Additionally, I would also like to get an idea of various techniques how to gauge how much is right and when you have crossed the line. E.g. can any blood work labs give a clear indication that you are doing too much?

Comment: After you exercise a body part and it becomes soar, give it time to recover (i.e. not soar) before you work it again. If your chest is soar, work legs the next day and shoulders the day after. In 3 days, your chest should be recovered.

Answer (score 1):

"Overtraining" is best described as "Outworking your body's ability to recover". The symptoms for it can be extremely broad depending on how deep in overtraining you are.

The [National Academy of Sports Medicine](https://blog.nasm.org/strategies-for-overcoming-overtraining) actually lists a variety of symptoms that are indicative of overtraining which I'll list in case the link gets broken.

1. A plateau or decline in workout performance or progress.
2. A perception of increased exertion during “normal” or “easy” workouts.
3. Excessive sweating or overheating.
4. Unusual feelings of heaviness, stiffness, or soreness in muscles.
5. A lack of feeling “refreshed” after regular rest and recovery.
6. Recurrent injuries, such as muscle sprains, tendonitis, stress fractures, and chronic joint pain.
7. A decline in enthusiasm for exercise (or skipping or quitting workouts).
8. Persistent feelings of fatigue, exhaustion, or low energy throughout the day.
9. A decline in motivation and/or self-confidence.
10. A lack of enjoyment in favorite hobbies and interests or other signs of depression.
11. Unusual mood or emotions, such as agitation, anger, confusion, irritability, and restlessness.
12. New problems with sleeping, including insomnia and poor sleep quality.
13. Problems with concentration and performance at work or in school.
14. A sickly appearance, including changes to skin, hair, and nails (such as acne or hair loss).
15. An increase in resting heart rate and/or resting blood pressure.
16. Unplanned/undesired weight loss or weight gain or disordered eating.
17. Digestive issues, such as constipation, diarrhea, loss of appetite, and increase in thirst.
18. Reproductive issues, such as a decrease in libido (sex drive) and a change in menstruation (including irregularity or cessation of periods).
19. Repeated bouts of illness, such as colds and upper respiratory tract infections.

Regarding blood markers, they state

> Researchers, healthcare providers, and fitness professionals may suggest lab testing such as blood tests to measure levels of nutrients (like electrolytes or iron), hormones (like cortisol, thyroid, and testosterone), or other factors (like blood count and signs of inflammation).

However, I would say getting blood assessments to gauge if you're overtraining is overkill (although it's always a good idea to get checked every once in a while for general health).  The easiest way would be to just simply assess how you are feeling.

Did you have two or three really bad workouts in a row?

Are you unable to easily do things you were capable of doing a week ago?

Is your resting heart rate higher?

Are you having trouble sleeping?

Are you constantly sick?

Do you have problems eating?

If you answered "Yes" to most of these questions, then you are overtraining. You likely need to take it easy for a few days and then you'll be right back to baseline and can continue training as normal. The amount of rest you need would depend on how severe the symptoms are. If you're just simply tired and sore on a training day, then you probably can just go light or skip the workout entirely and you'll be fine.  If you're pale in the face, your heart is beating rapidly while sitting, and your body is all puffy from holding water, then you may need a week or two off to fully recover.

Comment: I've replaced the code formatting, we should avoid using code formatting for things that aren't code, screen readers typically don't handle it very well.